# _CookieConsentPartial.cshtml not found in asp.net core 3.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 3.0.But in my application i couldn't find the file called _CookieConsentPartial.cshtml.

I am unable to find the file under presentation layer/views/shared.Can any one help me to find the file..

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookie consent has been removed from the templates in ASP.NET Core 3.0, you can refer to below article to enable the default cookie consent feature like that found in the ASP.NET Core 2.2 templates :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-3.1